# Como extraer o pasar una variable (Dato) que se encuentra en un método a una variable externa?

Tags: java, android

Tengo un método dentro de un activity el cual envía una variable por medio del método `GET` a un WebService en donde se ejecuta una consulta SQL para que me retorne el tipo de usuario.

Hasta el momento todo bien solo que no he logrado tomar ese dato que esta dentro del `ArrayList` el cual trae el tipo de usuario que consulto en la tabla Mysql, ya probe con una variable con `GET`  y `SET` y no me toma el dato y ps con `return` no seria posible ya que el metodo es tipo `Void`.

Algun consejo?

Publico aqui el metodo para la consulta :

```
String URL = "http://192.168.0.111/proyecto_joinder/Search_user.php?email="+inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
EnviarRecibirDatos(URL);






  public void EnviarRecibirDatos(String URL){

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+URL, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            if (response.length()>0){
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    Log.i("sizejson",""+jsonArray.length());
                    CargarArray(jsonArray);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    queue.add(stringRequest);

}



public void CargarArray(JSONArray ja){

    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++){

        try {
            lista.add(0,ja.getString(0));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Datos Recuperados : " + lista.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //Aqui muestro el dato que se encuentra en lista.get(0) para comprobar que si lo estuviera recibiendo y efectivamente lo hace.
    //setDato(lista.get(0));


}
```

Comment: Hey Checho, no has leído el [tour]. Te comento que en este caso es importante sabe cual es la respuesta que obtienes en onResponse(), esto para saber como tratar tu información, tal vez response no es un JSONArray.  Agrega esta información.

Comment: Te lanza algun error? Si te retorna datos, como te lo retorna? Puedes darnos un ejemplo del json que el servidor te retorna?

Comment: Hola Jorge y Einer, ps el `Response` que trae la respuesta del servidor me retorna lo siguiente ["2"], es justo ese dato el que necesito sacar del metodo y ponerlo en alguna variable global o algun otro metodo para luego enviarlo a otro activity que es donde lo necesito.

Comment: El problema es que no se guarda en la variable global y le pongo un Toast para ver si realmente esta recibiendo el dato y no muestra nada en pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione, había olvidado algo tan básico pero a la vez muy importante y es que Java va leyendo segundo el orden, entonces cuando ponía a mostrar el contenido de la variable ps obviamente no arrojaba nada ya que todavía no la había recibido.